# Calculating percentage basics

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am new to this website, so please forgive my mistakes if there is any.

I'm not quite good standing with mathematics and I have trouble finding the solution for this problem:

**60%** of the number **50** equals **30**. I know this from my own logic, but how would I solve the issue mathematically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $60\%$ is the same as $\frac{60}{100}=\frac{6}{10}$.

So you just need to compute the product $$\frac{6}{10}\times 50.$$

Comment: Thank you. This is something I definitely won't ever forget anymore.

Comment: If you want to compute how much $p\%$ is you compute as  above *but* if you want to add $p\%$ to a number $x$, just compute the product $(100+p)/100\times x$ to obtain $x+p/100\times x$.